# Why are my PHP sessions not being created?

Tags: php, session, hosting, host, session-storage

I have a website hosted by [FatCow](http://www.fatcow.com/).

I am trying to install the Securimage PHP CAPTCHA on my site by mimicking their [quickstart guide](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/documentation/quickstart-guide/), but it failed to work off the bat, so I ran their [PHP Test Script](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/downloads/securimage_test.php) on my site to determine the problem.

It threw this error:

> The following error occurred when attempting to call session_start():
>   session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/temp/sess_5e72461407b4ac6283d9897cc49dc4e3, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)

Now, I had an issue before surrounding sessions, so I made a temp folder through my FTP client on my domain's home ('/') folder, and set its file permissions to 777. Then I had proceeded to put a php.ini file also in my domain's home folder with the following declarations:

```
session.save_path = "/temp"
session.cookie_path = "/temp"
```

What is the issue? Why can't it create these sessions?

Comment: Well, I linked the PHP Test Script, so if you browse to it you'll see its almost at the very top.

Comment: FatCow has a [help page for this](http://www.fatcow.com/knowledgebase/beta/article.bml?ArticleID=1290).

Comment: Nice. That's a good find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the system doesn't contain a temp/tmp directory, this appears to be a hosting configuration issue, so you'd have to take that up with your provider.

Your solution to create your own temp directory may work, but your path wouldn't be correct.  "/" is only the root as perceived by your FTP session because FTP sessions are typically chroot'd.  Your home's root directory as perceived by the web server is going to be your home directory, which may be something like /home/my-domain.  You can use the PHP [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) function to find out exactly what it is.

Comment: Sweet man, I thought it might be something like this. I'll look into that now. I was looking for a few hours for some information on how that worked.